# Where is the implementation of "getaddrinfo" called by InetAddress.java

Tags: android, ipv6

I have been recently studying on why the Browser in the android OS 
does not support accessing IPv6 websites through IPv6 URLs and 
I think it is due to the native method `getaddrinfo` called by `android/dalvik/libcore/luni/src/main/java/java/net/ 
InetAddress.java` which is then called by the Browser application 
throws an `UnknownHostException` when trying to convert an IPv6 URL to 
its addresses.

Begin from line 507, the code of `InetAddress.java` is:

```
try {   
    InetAddress[] addresses = bytesToInetAddresses(getaddrinfo(host), host);   
    addressCache.put(host, addresses);   
    return addresses;
```

and the native method is declared at line 516 as:

```
private static native byte[][] getaddrinfo(String name) 
        throws UnknownHostException;
```

But I haven't found any hint about where the implementation of this 
native method `getaddrinfo` is although I found there are two files 
named `getaddrinfo.c`. Does here follow the rules of JNI or NDK? If 
so, a statement of `System.loadLibary("NameOfTheLibrary")` should be 
found but I didn't find it.
Any one could give me a hint on finding the implementation of this 
native method `getaddrinfo`?

The complete source file of `InetAddress.java` can be found at http://ooowjc.wikispaces.com/Attachments

Answer (score 3):

In the Android source tree, libcore/luni/src/main/native/java_net_InetAddress.cpp.

I'd include a link to the file in the android-git repository, but the [site](http://android.git.kernel.org/) seems to be hosed at the moment.

Comment: Yes, it can be implemented in C++. But even it is implemented in C++, it should follow the JNI rule so I still could not understand.

Comment: It follows "Class_method", in this case InetAddress_getaddrinfo().  The file is named after the class (java.net.InetAddress).